# How to add script config.ini to pip package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

i have script which use `configparser`

My package folder structure is:

```
-- package_name/
   -- src/
      --package_script/(scriptfiles)
      --config/(config .ini to parse)
   -- setup.py(etc)
```

In script i use:

```
def config_read ():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.sections()
    config.read('../config/config.ini')
    print(str(datetime.now()) + ' - Config have been read successfully')
    return config
```

in setup.py added:

```
package_data={'src': ['config/*', ]},
```

Check dist before upload (*.tar) there all is ok. Folder `config` with `config.ini`.

But when i use `pip install package_name` and the use command to start (command included)
Errors:

```
File "c:\users\hell\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\src\package_name\script.py", line 110, in main
    logged = login(config['Userinfo']['user'], config['Userinfo']['password'])
  File "c:\users\hell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\configparser.py", line 959, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Userinfo'
```

Package script can't fide config.ini,

Comment: Verify that `c:\users\hell\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\src\package_name\config\config.ini` exists. Show us the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `config.read('../config/config.ini')` loads config related to the current directory. It really should be related to the script. Something like

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
config.read(script_dir + '/../config/config.ini')
```